# Active record foreign key custom naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know active record require for User use user_id if you want to set up foreign key, but for project needed we must use three different fields for storing different users (responsible,executor,validation users)

So now it looks like

```
Task
-----------
name | date | until | initiation | validation | execution
```

I think it should looks like

```
has_one :user,class => User,:as=> :initiation
```

or similar, but still cant find right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have Task model and it has three types of users handling it. You want to refer to them all, right?

If so, then first put initiation_id, validation_id and execution_id fields in your tasks table through a migration. Then try this in your Task model:

```
has_one :initiation, :class => "User", :foreign_key => :initiation_id
has_one :validation, :class => "User", :foreign_key => :validation_id
has_one :execution, :class => "User", :foreign_key => :execution_id
```

Hope I understood you right.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure to understand what you need, but I think you are either looking for [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) or [Single Table Inheritance (STI)](http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails).

Either way, there is a [Railscast-episode on this topic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations) (pro only) - you should see if it is what you are looking for.